# Access files(read them) and read the directory structure using javascript in all browsers

Tags: javascript, file-io

I have had a look at the pollyfills , but websql is not supported in IE8 and 9 , so even if I use IndexedDbshim for supporting IndexedDB for accessing the filesystem , my purpose is not solved. I know we can do it using server side scripting , I have tried doing the same using node , but is there any way , or any other polyfill available where we can do it all the browsers ?